# Open portoflio item in above div with easing

Tags: html, toggle, easing

I'm failry new to the whole jquery thing, but right now I'm building a portfolio and I need help with the effect I want to achieve.

I have several items in my portfolio, all are set up the same way:

```
<div class="portfolio_item">
<div class="portfolio_thumb"><a href="linktofullview.php"><img src="image.png"></a></div>
<h5><a href="linktofullview.php">Title</a></h5>
<div class="portfolio_description">Lorem ipsum dolor ...</div>
</div>
```

Now I want the "fullview" to appear ABOVE the entire portfolio items. Clicking on the portfolio_thumb image or the title will open up a div above with easing, revealing the details and other images.

How can I achieve this?!

Similar to this :http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-sliding-navigation/ but only above the items, and for several items, that open in the same div.

Thanks so much in advance.